Access to variables in JSON response
I've trying to access variables within a JSON response I am using on IMEI.org site using PHP.
So I submit my request and I get this JSON response:
{"status":1,"response":{"Model":"iPhone 6 32GB Space Gray [iPhone7,2]   [A1586]","IMEI":"35xxxxxxxxxxxxx","Serial  Number":"F6Wxxxxxxxxx","FMI":"ON","iCloud":"CLEAN","Carrier":"Unlock","Country":"N\/A","Simlock":"U NLOCKED"}}

So I now want to access the different variables in this response.
For example, I want to just display the Model and perhaps another variable like Simlock, but no matter what I try I can't seem to display this.
I have tried to decode the JSON response with json_decode($data) - (where $data is the JSON response), but still cannot access these variables.
Any idea how I can access this data?
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data);
echo $characters->status;
echo $characters->imei;
echo $characters->response->services[1]->name;


The JSON seems to be valid: https://3v4l.org/XFNL0 and I can get what's there: https://3v4l.org/ZM9A8 Maybe pay more attention to the case of the characters and where the items are in the structure?

Thanks @KIKOSoftware. I'm not sure what I was doing as I had tried several different solutions but yours has worked for me - finally! Thanks.
